# how to get the value of a discrete array?

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to get the value of discrete array, for example:

```
scores = [ (500, 1), (450, 3), (400, 6), (300, 7), (225, 9) ]
```

this means `( value, rank )`, for example there `3-1=2` `500`, `6-3=3` `450`, so the real list is:

```
[ 500, 500, 450, 450, 450, 400, 300, 300, 225]
```

now, given a list of rank, I want to know what is the value of these ranks, such as `[1, 5, 7, 8]`, the `1st` value is 500, `5th` value is 450, `7th` value is 300, `8th` value is 300, so this return `[500, 450, 300, 300]`

how can I do this effectively?

---

Edit:

let's say `len(scores)` is M, the desired list length is N, M >> N, and `M` can be very very large(anyway this is a statics result of 3GB data).

---

My mistake:

this is needed: the `max rank` of `score` should be given, so that the number of the last one could be know.

And another thing should be important: scores are not sorted, so it could be:

```
scores = [(450, 3), (300, 7), (500, 1), (400, 6), (255, 9)]
total = 10 # this means we get two 255 here
```

Comment: Can you give some rough estimation for M and N? It matters how "M >> N" they are.

Comment: @StefanPochmann for just now, N is less than 10, M can be 10^3 ~ 10^4.

Answer (score 3):

If we can assume that the ranks in `scores` appear in sorted order, then we can
use [`bisect.bisect_right`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_right) to find the desired index in `O(log(n))` time.
If `len(scores)` is large, this will be quicker than looping through `scores`
for each value in `ranks`:

```
import bisect
import operator

scores = [ (500, 1), (450, 3), (400, 6), (300, 7), (225, 9) ]
values, cutoffs = zip(*scores)
ranks = [1, 5, 7, 8]
print([values[bisect.bisect_right(cutoffs, rank)-1] for rank in ranks])
```

yields

```
[500, 450, 300, 300]
```

---

For very large `len(scores)`, or `len(ranks)` you will get better performance using [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/). The NumPy equivalent of `bisect.bisect` is [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html). Notice, however, that `np.searchsorted` can take a whole list (or array) of `ranks` as an argument and return an array of indices whereas `bisect.bisect` must be called once for each `rank`.
So the problem can be solved with only one call to `np.searchsorted`:

```
import numpy as np

scores = np.array([ (500, 1), (450, 3), (400, 6), (300, 7), (225, 9) ])
values, cutoffs = scores[:,0], scores[:,1]
ranks = [1, 5, 7, 8]

print(values[np.searchsorted(cutoffs, ranks, side='right')-1])
# [500, 450, 300, 300]
```

---

Below are some benchmarks when `len(scores)` is moderately large. Given this setup:

```
import bisect
import numpy as np

scores = [ (500, 1), (450, 3), (400, 6), (300, 7), (225, 9) ]
scores = np.array(scores * 2000).cumsum(axis=0)
values, cutoffs = scores[:,0], scores[:,1]
ranks = cutoffs[::100]
scores_list = list(map(tuple, scores))
ranks_list = list(ranks)

def using_numpy(scores, ranks):
    # ranks does not have to be in sorted order
    scores = np.asarray(scores)
    values, cutoffs = scores[:,0], scores[:,1]
    return values[np.searchsorted(cutoffs, ranks, side='right')-1]

def using_bisect(scores, ranks):
    # ranks does not have to be in sorted order
    values, cutoffs = zip(*scores)
    return [values[bisect.bisect_right(cutoffs, rank)-1] for rank in ranks]

def using_reverse(scores, ranks):
    # ranks must be sorted for this method to work
    ranks.sort()
    values = []
    i = len(scores) - 1
    for rank in reversed(ranks):
        while scores[i][1] > rank:
            i -= 1
        values.append(scores[i][0])
    values = values[::-1]
    return values
```

this checks that the results are the same:

```
for func in (using_reverse, using_bisect):
    assert np.allclose(func(scores_list, ranks_list), using_numpy(scores, ranks))
```

This shows `using_numpy` is far faster than `using_reverse` *if you pass a NumPy array to `using_numpy` and lists to `using_reverse`*:

```
In [241]: %timeit using_numpy(scores, ranks)
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.58 µs per loop

In [239]: %timeit using_reverse(scores_list, ranks_list)
1000 loops, best of 3: 827 µs per loop

In [250]: %timeit using_bisect(scores_list, ranks_list)
1000 loops, best of 3: 835 µs per loop
```

If you include the time required to convert the lists `scores_list` into a NumPy
array, then `using_numpy` becomes slower than `using_reverse`:

```
In [242]: %timeit using_numpy(scores_list, ranks_list)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.77 ms per loop
```

However, normally when you are using NumPy, you construct the arrays *once*, and
then perform many calculations. So while the conversion to NumPy arrays is
expensive, it is a one-time cost of, say <4ms (for the example above). After
which, you get to enjoy fast NumPy-based computations (which, in the case above,
is almost 100x faster). If your program is so short as to finish in a time that
is on the order of 4ms, then the conversion to NumPy arrays might be
prohibitively expensive. However, if your program takes significantly longer
than 4ms (which is usually the case when performance matters), then the conversion to NumPy arrays would be a small price to pay.

Comment: Thanks for the improved benchmarks :-). Btw, do you know whether there's a "smarter" version of `searchsorted` in numpy or maybe a related library? One that can take advantage of the second array being sorted as well, and doing something like I do instead of binary searches?

Comment: thanks a lot, but I find `bisect` or `numpy` both can not deal with `None`, such as I want to find `[1, 1, None]`, what I prefer is `[500, 500, 0]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. I process scores and ranks in parallel by primarily walking over the ranks and tagging an index into scores along appropriately. I go backwards because that's easier. If you have many scores and only few ranks to look up, then binary search might be better.

```
values = []
i = len(scores) - 1
for rank in reversed(ranks):
    while scores[i][1] > rank:
        i -= 1
    values.append(scores[i][0])
values = values[::-1]
```

Or if you meant *"effectively"* as in short/simple code, here are two ways:

```
>>> [min(v for v, r in scores if r <= rank) for rank in ranks]
[500, 450, 300, 300]

>>> [next(v for v, r in scores[::-1] if r <= rank) for rank in ranks]
[500, 450, 300, 300]
```

---

**Update:** I just saw the benchmarks of @unutbu and since he ignored the preparation costs for his fastest solution and gave an unfit datatype to the other solutions and ignored my main solution (just benchmarking my slow ones??) and used the original `ranks` without adapting it to his vastly different `scores`, I did a fairer comparison myself:

(**Update 2:** unutbu updated his benchmarks and fixed all those issues)

```
same result: True
7.620430773809753 seconds for numpy
4.5830411517407095 seconds for parallel
```

That's with unutbu's `scores` but changed to the original datatype (list of tuples) and with adapted `ranks`. It's 10000 scores and 100 ranks spread out like the original (I also tried with 10 ranks and 1000 ranks, the times didn't change much). The code:

```
from timeit import timeit
import numpy as np

def search_numpy(scores, ranks):
    scores = np.array(scores)
    values, cutoffs = scores[:,0], scores[:,1]
    return values[np.searchsorted(cutoffs, ranks, side='right')-1]

def search_parallel(scores, ranks):
    values = []
    i = len(scores) - 1
    for rank in reversed(ranks):
        while scores[i][1] > rank:
            i -= 1
        values.append(scores[i][0])
    return values[::-1]

scores = np.array([ (500, 1), (450, 3), (400, 6), (300, 7), (225, 9) ] * 2000).cumsum(axis=0)
values, cutoffs = scores[:,0], scores[:,1]
ranks = cutoffs[::100]
scores = list(map(tuple, scores))
ranks = list(ranks)
print('same result:', all(search_parallel(scores, ranks) == search_numpy(scores, ranks)))
print(timeit(lambda: search_numpy(scores, ranks), number=1000), 'seconds for numpy')
print(timeit(lambda: search_parallel(scores, ranks), number=1000), 'seconds for parallel')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rank = [1, 5, 7, 8]
scores = [ (500, 1), (450, 3), (400, 6), (300, 7), (225, 9) ]
arr = []
for i in xrange(1, len(scores)):
    arr.extend([scores[i-1][0]] * abs(scores[i][1] - scores[i-1][1]))

arr.append(scores[-1][0])
print arr

for i in rank:
    print arr[i-1],

>>> [500, 500, 450, 450, 450, 400, 300, 300, 225]
>>> 500 450 300 300
```

Comment: That was me, because you only expanded to the full values list and didn't produce the actual desired goal list. You fixed that in the meantime, but expanding to the full list also doesn't strike me as doing it "effectively", which is what the OP asked for, so I'm undecided whether I should undo the vote :-|

Comment: No worries @StefanPochmann, Your valuable insights are always helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Created two functions:

**Function1**: Create Value of all Ranks from the 1 to last rank from the Input.

**Fucntion2**: Create target Value list from the Target Rank list and Value list

**Demo**:

```
def getScores(scores): 
    """ Create Value rank list from 1 to last rank"""
    start_rank = 1
    start_value = 0
    last_rank = scores[-1][1]
    value_scores = []
    for value, rank in scores:
        if start_rank==rank:
            value_scores.append(value)
            start_rank += 1
        elif start_rank<rank:
            # Set Previous Value to rank if not present in the Input.
            for j in range(start_rank, rank+1):
                value_scores.append(value)
                start_rank += 1

    return value_scores


def getRankScores(target_rank, value_scores):
    """ Get Target Rank Value"""

    target_values = []
    for i in target_rank:
        try:
            target_values.append(value_scores[i-1])
        except IndexError:
            #- Outof Range. 
            #Handle exception for Rank which value is not present in the Values.
            target_values.append(value_scores[-1])

    return target_values


scores = [ (500, 1), (450, 3), (400, 6), (300, 7), (225, 9) ]
target_rank = [1, 5, 7, 8]

value_scores = getScores(scores)
print  "value_scores:", value_scores

target_values = getRankScores(target_rank, value_scores)
print "Result:-", target_values
```

**Output**:

```
value_scores: [500, 450, 450, 400, 400, 400, 300, 225, 225]
Result:- [500, 400, 300, 225]
```

Comment: I don't think expanding it to the full is list doing it "effectively", and  it's also a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `itertools`.

```
import itertools

scores = [(500, 1), (450, 3), (400, 6), (300, 7), (225, 9)]
result = [[scores[i][0]for j in range(abs(scores[i+1][1]-scores[i][1]))] if i+1 != len(scores) else [scores[-1][0]] 
            for i in range(len(scores))]
score_list = list(itertools.chain(*result))

print score_list
```

Results:

```
[500, 500, 450, 450, 450, 400, 300, 300, 225]
```

Now based on the `score_list` you can get the value based on rank.

```
rank_list = [1, 5, 7, 8]

for i in rank_list:
    print "Score holding rank {} :- {}".format(i, score_list[i-1])
```

Displays:

```
Score holding rank 1 :- 500
Score holding rank 5 :- 450
Score holding rank 7 :- 300
Score holding rank 8 :- 300
```

Comment: That's not the desired result `[500, 450, 300, 300]`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Thanks for the comment. Please review my updated result.

Comment: That's better, but like I said about anmol's solution, expanding to the full list also doesn't strike me as doing it "effectively", which is what the OP asked for, so I'm undecided whether I should undo the vote :-|

Answer (score 0):

If I understand that correctly you do not have every rank-value-relation mapped in `scores`, but there is the rule: If you do not find the rank in scores, take the next smaller one.

In the following function I find the maximum rank (and the corresponding value) that is smaller or equal to the given rank. Then I just use this value.

```
def find_rank_value(to_be_looked_up_rank):
    proxy_rank, value = max((rank, value) for value, rank in scores if rank<= to_be_looked_up_rank)
    return value
```

Now we can use this function to generate a list of values, using list comprehensions.

```
list_of_ranks = [1, 5, 7, 8]

list_of_values = [find_rank_value(rank) for rank in list_of_ranks]

list_of_values
```

Out:

```
[500, 450, 300, 300]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scores = [(500, 1), (450, 3), (400, 6), (300, 7), (225, 9)]
ranks = [1, 5, 7, 8]

values = []
v, r = zip(*scores)
for rank in ranks:
    while rank not in r:
        rank -= 1
    values.append(v[r.index(rank)])
```